# Restricting road access by vehicle type using Network Analyst with ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, parameters, road

Is there a way to restrict road access by vehicle type using the Network Analyst extension with ArcMap?

Some roads restrict trucks, some roads have height/weight restrictions, and some roads are restricted by the type of license plate (e.g., commercial, personal, etc.).

I am familiar with restricting road access by height and weight of the vehicles, but I also want to add attributes into my Network Dataset to restrict road access by vehicle type (e.g., trucks) and type of license plate (e.g., commercial).

Answer (score 0):

To do this look at the section on **Assigning values to restrictions** in the Network Analyst page on [Types of evaluators used by a network](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/types-of-evaluators-used-by-a-network.htm):

> Each attribute defined in the network must have values for each source
>   participating in the network. An evaluator assigns values for the
>   attribute of each source. ... In ArcGIS, the field evaluator assigns
>   values to a network attribute from a field of a network source. In
>   addition, ArcGIS offers other types of evaluators that can be used,
>   for instance, constant, field expression, function, and script
>   evaluators.

...

> Restriction attributes have a Boolean data type. Since a source
>   element can either use or ignore the associated restriction, it can be
>   assigned a constant value of Use Restriction or Ignore Restriction.
>
> Alternatively, restriction attributes can be derived using the
>   function evaluator to compare another attribute to a parameter value.
>   For example, an attribute that models vehicle height restrictions can
>   use the function evaluator to compare the height limit of a road to
>   the vehicle's actual height stored in an attribute parameter. When the
>   expression evaluates to true, the restriction is used on the road;
>   when the expression evaluates to false, the restriction is ignored.
>   The exception to this rule is that anytime either of the operands
>   (MaxHeight or Vehicle Height) have a value of zero, the expression
>   always evaluates to false.